# I'm trying to search using a date range and copy data to a new destination

Tags: excel, date, vba

I got some great help on here setting up a search function that takes a changing input from a cell on a sheet and searches a different sheet for data matching whatever the input was (In this case it was a name). The code then returns the data from 3 columns in every row that matches the input. This works great, and I am thankful for the help. Now I am trying to alter that same concept to cover more columns (That was easy enough). However, I need to change the search parameter to a date range rather than a name input. I found an answer to a date range search on here, but I'm struggling to get it to work. Here is what I have at the moment.

```
Sub ARange()
Dim Sh As Worksheet: Set Sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim SRCH As Worksheet: Set SRCH = Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim i, j As Integer

LookupColumn = "A" 'Define the LookupColum / If you find using column index to be simpler then you need to switch the search from (range) to (cells)
StartDate_Value = SRCH.Range("a1").Value 'Use whatever you need to define the input values
EndDate_Value = SRCH.Range("a2").Value 'Use whatever you need to define the input values

For i = 1 To 30000
    If Sh.Range(LookupColumn & i).Value = EndDate_Value Then EndDate_Row = i
Next i

For j = EndDate_Row To 1 Step -1
    If Sh.Range(LookupColumn & j).Value = StartDate_Value Then StartDate_Row = j
Next j

    Call ExtractData

'Dim MyDateRange As Range: Set MyDateRange = Sh.Range(LookupColumn & StartDate_Row & ":" & LookupColumn & EndDate_Row)
'MsgBox "MyDateRange = " & LookupColumn & StartDate_Row & ":" & LookupColumn & EndDate_Row
End Sub
Sub ExtractData()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim LastRow As Long, RowCounter As Long
    Dim SearchRange As Range, FoundRange As Range, rw As Range
    Dim Val As String: Val = wsDest.Range("a1")
    'Call ARange

    With wsSrc
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Set SearchRange = .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, "H")) 'A2-H
        Set FoundRange = FindAll(Val, SearchRange)

    End With

    'Clear Destination Sheet (except header row)
    With wsDest
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.Intersect(wsDest.UsedRange, wsDest.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    ' Copy Data
    RowCounter = 2
    Set FoundRange = Union(FoundRange, FoundRange.EntireRow.Rows) 'Expand Range to entire rows of Range
    For Each rw In FoundRange.Rows
        wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 2) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 1)
        wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 3) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 2)
        wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 4) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 3)
        wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 5) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 4)
        wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 6) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 5)
        wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 7) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 6)
        wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 8) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 7)
        wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 9) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 8)
        RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
    Next rw

End Sub


Function FindAll(What, _
    Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
    Optional LookIn, _
    Optional LookAt, _
    Optional SearchOrder, _
    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional MatchByte, _
    Optional SearchFormat) As Range

    'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
     LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
     SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
     SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
     MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
     Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
     object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-"""

    Dim SrcRange As Range
    If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
        Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
        Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
        Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
    Else: SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If
    If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'get the first matching cell in the range first
    With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
        Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

    If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
        Set FindAll = CurrRange
        Do
            Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
            If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, CurrRange)
            Else: Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```

In this example I am calling the 'ExtractData' sub after running the date search. I have tried it the other way where I run the 'ExtractData' sub and call the 'ARange' sub. However, when running it the other way, 'ARange' only returns the message box and has no effect on the search. 
If I remove 'ARange' and just run the 'ExtractData' but input a single date, the search pulls the information I need for all entries with that date. So If there is a way to alter the 'ExtractData' module to search a given date range, that would be easiest. I have included below the 'ExtractData' module by itself. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub ExtractData()
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim LastRow As Long, RowCounter As Long
Dim SearchRange As Range, FoundRange As Range, rw As Range
Dim Val As String: Val = wsDest.Range("a1")


With wsSrc
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set SearchRange = .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, "H")) 'A2-H
    Set FoundRange = FindAll(Val, SearchRange)

End With

'Clear Destination Sheet (except header row)
With wsDest
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Intersect(wsDest.UsedRange, wsDest.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)).ClearContents
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

' Copy Data
RowCounter = 2
Set FoundRange = Union(FoundRange, FoundRange.EntireRow.Rows) 'Expand Range to entire rows of Range
For Each rw In FoundRange.Rows
    wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 2) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 1)
    wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 3) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 2)
    wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 4) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 3)
    wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 5) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 4)
    wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 6) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 5)
    wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 7) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 6)
    wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 8) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 7)
    wsDest.Cells(RowCounter, 9) = wsSrc.Cells(rw.Row, 8)
    RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
Next rw

End Sub

Function FindAll(What, _
Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
Optional LookIn, _
Optional LookAt, _
Optional SearchOrder, _
Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
Optional MatchByte, _
Optional SearchFormat) As Range

'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
 LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
 SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
 SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
 MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
 Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
 object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-"""

Dim SrcRange As Range
If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
    Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
    Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
    Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
Else: SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
End If
If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

'get the first matching cell in the range first
With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
    Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
End With

Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
    SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
    Set FindAll = CurrRange
    Do
        Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
        If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
            Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, CurrRange)
        Else: Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Too much code for me to wrangle with.  Best advice is to make sure that your date format you are searching for matches the date format being searched.  DATEVALUE is a good method to lookup.

Comment: The format is the same for both, and I have no problem pulling all rows which have a matching date by using the current search function. The problem is, I cannot search a date range using that function. Thanks for taking minute to try and help.

Comment: I'm thinking I can change a single line in the ExtractData Sub `Dim Val As String: Val = wsDest.Range("a1")` and solve my problem, but I have no idea what to switch it to.

Comment: ok. But changing `Dim Val As string: Val = wsDest.Range("a1")` to `Dim Val As Date: Val = wsDest.Range("a1")` doesn't resolve my need to search a date range. How would I change this dim to include 2 cells and search a range between 2 given dates? Or is this something that needs to be done with a call to another sub? I've tried that, but apparently I don't know where to put the call, because it does nothing.

Comment: I'm going to have to read your code.  Mihgt take a while.

Comment: OK, I'm looking at your code.  The top "Sub ARange()" really doesn't do anything.  It creates two private variables start-row and end-row, but destroys them when you leave that procedure.  In essence, it does nothing. Why use it? in the called procedure "ExtractData()" you redefine the start date and send it to "FindAll()", which is supposed to return a range of cells that contain the start date?  What if they are not contiguous cells? I would suggest losing the range method and instead get an array of all cell addresses containing the date you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This simple function will return an array with all cell addresses that contain a match to the search term, or date in your case.  Then you can use the array addresses to do what ever you need to do with those cells.  Try the "testBelow" procedure to test the function.  Fill your sheet range with dates and use the function to find all instances of that date in your sheet.

```
Sub testBelow()
Dim myArray1() As Variant

myArray1 = findInMultipleColumns(DateValue("02/21/2017"), Sheet1.Range("A1:H50"))

If myArray1(1) = "" Then
    Beep
    MsgBox "Match not found"
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = LBound(myArray1) To UBound(myArray1)
    Debug.Print myArray1(i)
Next i

End Sub

Public Function findInMultipleColumns(searchTerm As String, searchRng As Range) As Variant()

Dim myArray() As Variant, arrayCounter As Long

ReDim myArray(1 To 1)
arrayCounter = 1

With searchRng
    Set c = .Find(searchTerm, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            ReDim Preserve myArray(1 To arrayCounter)
            myArray(arrayCounter) = Replace(c.Address, "$", "")
            arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

findInMultipleColumns = myArray
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks John. I greatly appreciate the effort and assistance. I am out for the remainder of the week. I will have to review this on my return. Thank you again.